# ng-map :Can't get map object into the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, ng-map

As shown in this example of using direction api of ngmap, a map variable is used to get the total length of the route.

```
{{map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].overview_path.length}}
```

as in the example below.

view-source:https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/directions.html

But i want that variable inside my controller because I want to make my own direction-panel

I tried using `$scope.map` in the controller, but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, you want to initilize the map object like so:

```js
  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
   map.setOptions({
   });
  });
```

Obviously, any options you want to set on init would be declared in side map.setOptions.

Once that is initialized, you should be able to reference it using $scope.map